# how to display text and link in ul

Tags: css, text, html-lists

Trying to make this effect where I have a `ul` with links but text ***next*** to it too.

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a><p>description about item</p></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a><p>description about item</p></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a><p>description about item</p></li>
</ul>
```

But as you can see it makes the description below the item. Is there a way to make it next to the link?

many thanks

Comment: can you kind of explain more about how you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.goolge.com">Test</a> Description<li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag `<p>` has `display: block` property. This makes content into it to go to new line.

Depending on what you want you could remove `<p>` tag, or move whole `<a>` inside it.

Check the snippet.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a> description about item</li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a> description about item</li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <a href="#">item 3</a> description about item
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add span to the other text and add display block to it.

[image][image]